# XLINQ : Missing element in xml

Tags: linq-to-xml

i have the following xml

```
<students>
  <student>
    <id>12</id>
    <name>Mohsan</name>
  </student>
  <student>
    <id>2</id>    
  </student>
  <student>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>Azhar</name>
  </student>
</students>
```

note that in 2 name element is missing.

i have to read this xml using Linq to XML

i used following code to get all students..

please suggest me improvement in this code

```
var stds = from std in doc.Descendants("student")
                select new
                {
                    ID = std.Element("id").Value,
                    Name = (std.Element("name")!=null)?std.Element("name").Value:string.Empty
                };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the fact that there's an [explicit conversion from `XElement` to `string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263.aspx), which returns null for a null `XElement` reference. You can then use the null-coalescing operator to go from null to an empty string:

```
var stds = from std in doc.Descendants("student")
           select new
           {
               ID = std.Element("id").Value,
               Name = (string) std.Element("name") ?? "";
           };
```

Answer (score 5):

Syntax with 'let' allows you avoid twice ask Element("name")

```
var stds = from std in doc.Descendants("student")
            let elName = std.Element("name") 
            select new
            {
                ID = std.Element("id").Value,
                Name = (elName!=null)?elName.Value:string.Empty
            };
```

Comment: can i use ?? for this. it is giving me error. 

Name = std.Element("name")??string.Empty

Comment: @Mohsan std.Element("name")?? - resolve XML element, but not  string, on other hand string.Empty is a string, so it is type incompatibility. Unfortunately std.Element("name").ToString() ?? will also fail since NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late, but may help someone else looking through this. I had a rather large object with 90 properties I was trying to cast into from an XML file, so to make things easier I created a few methods.

```
    private static object CheckElement(XElement element)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)element) ? null : element.Value;
    }

    public static string CheckElementString(XElement element)
    {
        return (string)CheckElement(element);
    }

    public static Int16 CheckElementInt(XElement element)
    {
        var theResult = CheckElement(element);

        return theResult == null ? (short)-1 : Convert.ToInt16(theResult);
    }

    public static DateTime? CheckElementDateTimeNullable(XElement element)
    {
        var theResult = CheckElement(element);

        return theResult == null ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(theResult.ToString());
    }

    public static decimal CheckElementDecimal(XElement element)
    {
        var theResult = CheckElement(element);

        return theResult == null ? 0.00M : Convert.ToDecimal(theResult);
    }

    public static bool CheckElementBoolean(XElement element, bool defaultValue)
    {
        var theResult = CheckElement(element);

        return theResult == null ? defaultValue : Convert.ToBoolean(theResult);
    }
```

Then it was pretty easy to use like this:

```
    var stds = from std in doc.Descendants("student")
        select new
        {
            ID = std.Element("id").Value,
            Name = CheckElementString(std.Element("name"))
        };
```